# Does anyone know how to connect a docker container to my local area network

Tags: networking, docker

I have my local area network as 192.168.1.0/24 and would love if I could make a container that can be  given an IP within that subnet and can then communicate with all the devices in my LAN . I would love if someone could either send some links or a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

docker run -d -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp  my_bind9_image

53:53 means container_port:host_port

It's like port forwarding on a firewall.